# Need countdown timer from specified Denmark time to current time

Tags: javascript, prestashop, countdown, countdowntimer

I am in need of countdown timer to make it display in product page of Prestashop package. It should calculate the difference between specified time of Denmark and current time of the local system.

Eg.
Specified time of Denmark - 16hrs : 00mins : 00secs Denmark time
Current time of the system - now();

var requiredTime = (specified_Time - current_Time)

I have added my code here. I wish experts to help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p align="center">Timer Result</p>
<p align="center"><span id="countdown"></span></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
// set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date("Aug 15, 2019").getTime();

// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {

// find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
var current_date = new Date().getTime();
var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

// do some time calculations
days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

// format countdown string + set tag value
countdown.innerHTML = days + "d, " + hours + "h, "
+ minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s";  

}, 1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly help me in this regards.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [getTimezoneOffset()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp) method for getting difference between UTC and Local Time and find out what  difference between UTC time and Denmark , so you will be able to include this difference in you calculation